# Will the Netgear LM1200 4G LTE Modem work with the Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, internet, modem

I'm working on a robot whose processing is all done in the cloud, and the raspberry pi only sends/receives/executes orders. For this reason, a way to have internet anywhere is needed, and I figured out the best and easiest way is through a SIM modem.

My question is, **has anyone tried the [Netgear LM1200 4G LTE Modem](https://amzn.eu/d/cCToslS)?** Will it work with the latest Raspbian (I think it's Bullseye)? Theoretically it's literally the same as using a router, but this time the LAN cable comes from this modem. I'll be using a SIM with a 4G LTE plan from Telekom on it.

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You've somehow managed to botch the URL for the modem... please try again.

Comment: @Seamus I fixed the broken link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This modem should work with a RPi. According to the [Product Documentation](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81lg7wGO8nL.pdf), it has a LAN Ethernet port that you can connect to your RPi (via Ethernet cable of course).

It also has a web-based interface for configuring the LAN interface; you'll use this to configure the DHCP server (internal to the modem) and the other "usual stuff". This means you'll need a web browser to access the interface - which can come from your RPi or another computer. Also, if you have an existing WiFi router/AP, you could connect that to the modem and then connect your RPi via WiFi.

It's a bit of an odd device in that it has a WAN interface for connecting a broadband router/modem for "backup", but I assume you're using it as a "stand-alone" device. So yes - this should work with an RPi.

Comment: So, in general, any SIM-baser modem that has a LAN port should work? I was also looking at this [Tenda 4G03 4G](https://amzn.eu/d/emzn0GC). It should work too, right?

Comment: @Mito: Maybe - I don't really know. It certainly doesn't have a good rating from other buyers.